# Can you install a single network printer on Ubuntu 22.04? I

Tags: networking, command-line, drivers, printing, hp

I am very new to Ubuntu. I write on Libre Office,Firefox, and Email. For most of my life I have used Windows.  I was told by a computer repair service any HP printer will install in Linux. My Canon printer died  and the new one I got was impossible to set up. I have been able to figure out this: go to the FireFox Browser  put in the command line  lpstat -t.  I am asking for help to find out: what commands go after lpstat -t to get a printer to run? There is a section on printers and I read to use  the command hplip  but I don't know what to put after it to add the printer successfully.

I have looked for an answer on similar recent questions. I haven't found an answer I, a new Ubuntu user, can understand. All I need are the command lines to make the printer install and run. I understand the function of command lines even though I am a Windows user.

Also can a single HP printer run on a wireless network? Or do you need to use a USB cable only ? I read in the Q & A here it can't run single on a home network and you need use a cable. I
Thank you so much for your help:-}

Comment: There should be no issues printing over the network as I do this all the time with my Epson. To set it up all I had to do was ensure the printer was on. Ubuntu found the printer and installed the driver itself. After that, I could print without first needing to walk over to the printer to turn it on.

Comment: Thank you . What commands do you use to set up a printer ? How do you install one? I have only added a printer in Windows.

Comment: Was it plug and play?

Comment: It was plug-and-play, yes. I don't have an HP, but consumer Canon and Epson printers have not been an issue for me for quite some time.

Comment: I was looking at Epson printers after your post. It could be the level of printers I have been looking at. Can your recommend one that is budget friendly?

Comment: Even a Canon the one we bought was Pixma MG3620 and the directions were very confusing because the LInux sustem couldn't read the CD meant for Windows.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on installing HP printers https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-networked-hp-printer-and-scanner-on-ubuntu-linux/. There should be printer setup/management tool installed by default - search applications on your system and with that it is pretty straight forward to add a printer - just follow the on screen instructions. Hope this is useful.

Comment: "*go to the FireFox Browser put in the command line lpstat -t*" Those are two different methods. Do not mix them together.

Comment: This tutorial looks easy I as long as I run this window with Firefox or copy down the commands. Very nice thank you both.